# HANA SQL Select table into variable and for loop issue

Tags: sql, variables, hana

I have a table in HANA that has the following columns:
Customer(varchar), Day(varchar), Item(varchar), Quantity (decimal), Cost(decimal)

My goal is to have a sql procedure that will duplicate the table values and append them to the existing table daily, while also updating the Day column values with the next day. So it will just be the same data over and over but new values for the Day column.

I believe this needs a select * from the table into a variable, then loop through the variable in which the Day column values will push forward 1 day, and then an insert all the updates rows. I'm stuck in the part of testing out the selection of 1 column and declaring it into a variable, and keep receiving this error:

```
DO
BEGIN
    DECLARE V1 VARCHAR(20);
    SELECT 'ITEM' INTO V1 FROM "TABLE_NAME";
    SELECT :V1 FROM "TABLE_NAME";
END;
```

DBTech JDBC: fetch returns more than requested number of rows: "TABLE_NAME"."(DO statement)": line 4 col 5 (at pos 43):

Comment: HANA <> MySQL <> SQL Server.  I've removed the conflicting tags.  Please make sure to tag appropriately in order to attract the best audience to help.

Comment: To clarify: only the entries for a single day should ever be “copied” forward, right? It’s not desired to copy previously copied days as well, correct?

Comment: correct, just previous days to be copied and new date inserted

Answer (score 1):

if you want to double your values, you don't need loops or variables.

the following doubles all ITEMs with a curent timestamp

```
INSERT INTO "TABLE_NAME"

("ITEM", "MYDATETIME")

SELECT "ITEM", NOW ( ) 
FROM "TABLE_NAME";
```

Comment: Getting this error: DBTech JDBC: [260]: invalid column name: MYDATETIME

Comment: "MYDATEtime is a placeholder for your time column as you didn't provide any information about your table so repace it with your datetime/timestamp column name

Comment: This worked, however it also changed the previous day's column values to the current day's. How do I keep the previous day's date in there?

Comment: i am unsre what you mean, if you had 20 rows in the table you now have 40. If you don't want all previous rows doubled, you have to add a WHERE to the SELCT and so reduce the number of rows, but that is basically another question

Comment: What I’m looking for is to duplicate the data which is what it does successfully, but keep the dates. So the first 20 rows are from 4/6 next 20 rows are from 4/6, and so on. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: that is no problem, use http://kabilsapworld.blogspot.com/2017/09/date-and-tme-functions-in-sap-hana.html at the pace where NOW()  and use adddays on the original date column

Comment: I meant first 20 rows from 4/5 and the next 20 rows are from 4/6. I’ll give this a try, thank you

Comment: yes even that os possible as you can use https://help.sap.com/viewer/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/Cloud/en-US/87f0d4985c4a49bfb64682dcb325173d.html  and then use the Div 20 to determine the dateadd number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243696/discussion-between-shaheed313-and-nbk).

Comment: As you maybe have problems with the algorithm i created a sample in ORALCLE, it uses special Oracle function, but as sample to get tit it should ssuffice https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=945db9d1d9ea474636771f48f434d628  it uses rownumber with DIV to determine the Group of items in the sample 5 that get 1 day. You have to adept it to HANA, espeuically the date_add

Comment: hi, this worked but how do i get it to copy only the previous day's data and not all of the old data? for example i have data starting on 4/19 and then 4/20 the data from 4/19 copies over. For 4/21 i only need the data from 4/20 copied over, not 4/19.

Comment: the modulo describes the marginb of rows in my sample the modulo was 5 so every 5 rows it changes,if you inly want secic dates change the where clause of the selct, but you ask for an algorithm which the sample fiddle shows

Answer (score 0):

The requirement seems to be:
*For each customer copy all entries of a reference day (e.g., the most recent entries) to new entries for the day following the reference day.*

Such a function could be supporting e.g., the daily "roll over" of inventory entries.

In its most basic form of requirements this can be achieved in plain SQL - no procedure code required.

```
create column table cust_items 
    (customer nvarchar(20)
    , i

tem_date date
        , item nvarchar(20)
        , quantity decimal (10,2)
        , cost decimal (10,2)) ;
    
insert into cust_items values ('Aardvark Inc.', add_days(current_date, -3), 'Yellow Balls', 10, 23.23);
insert into cust_items values ('Aardvark Inc.', add_days(current_date, -3), 'Bird Food', 4.5, 47.11);
insert into cust_items values ('Aardvark Inc.', add_days(current_date, -3), 'Carrot Cake', 3, 08.15);

insert into cust_items values ('Wolf Ltd.', add_days(current_date, -3), 'Red Ballon', 1, 47.11);
insert into cust_items values ('Wolf Ltd.', add_days(current_date, -3), 'Black Bile', 2, 23.23);
insert into cust_items values ('Wolf Ltd.', add_days(current_date, -3), 'Carrot Cake', 3, 08.15);

insert into cust_items values ('Wolf Ltd.', add_days(current_date, -2), 'Red Ballon', 1, 47.11);
insert into cust_items values ('Wolf Ltd.', add_days(current_date, -2), 'Black Bile', 2, 23.23);
insert into cust_items values ('Wolf Ltd.', add_days(current_date, -2), 'Carrot Cake', 3, 08.15);

select * from cust_items 
order by item_date, customer, item;

/*
CUSTOMER        ITEM_DATE   ITEM            QUANTITY    COST 
Aardvark Inc.   6 Apr 2022  Bird Food       4.5         47.11
Aardvark Inc.   6 Apr 2022  Carrot Cake     3           8.15 
Aardvark Inc.   6 Apr 2022  Yellow Balls    10          23.23
Wolf Ltd.       6 Apr 2022  Black Bile      2           23.23
Wolf Ltd.       6 Apr 2022  Carrot Cake     3           8.15 
Wolf Ltd.       6 Apr 2022  Red Ballon      1           47.11

Wolf Ltd.       7 Apr 2022  Black Bile      2           23.23
Wolf Ltd.       7 Apr 2022  Carrot Cake     3           8.15 
Wolf Ltd.       7 Apr 2022  Red Ballon      1           47.11
*/
```

We see that the two customers have individual entries, "Wolf Ltd." most recent entries are for April 7th, "Aardvark Inc." most recent entries are for April 6th.

The first part of the task now is to find the entries for most recent `ITEM_DATE` per customer. A simple join with a sub-query is sufficient here:

```
select co.customer, add_days(co.item_date, 1) as new_date, co.item, co.quantity, co.cost
from 
    cust_items co
    join (select customer, max(item_date) max_date
          from cust_items ci
          group by customer) m_date
     on (co.customer, co.item_date) 
      = (m_date.customer, m_date.max_date);

/* new date entries for each customer, based on previous most recent entry per customer
CUSTOMER        NEW_DATE    ITEM            QUANTITY    COST 
Aardvark Inc.   7 Apr 2022  Yellow Balls    10          23.23
Aardvark Inc.   7 Apr 2022  Bird Food       4.5         47.11
Aardvark Inc.   7 Apr 2022  Carrot Cake     3           8.15 
Wolf Ltd.       8 Apr 2022  Red Ballon      1           47.11
Wolf Ltd.       8 Apr 2022  Black Bile      2           23.23
Wolf Ltd.       8 Apr 2022  Carrot Cake     3           8.15 

*/
```

**Note**, the `add_days(co.item_date, 1) as new_date` function takes care of the "moving the day one day ahead" requirement.

The second part of the requirement is `INSERT`ing the new entries into the same table:

```
insert into cust_items
(select co.customer, add_days(co.item_date, 1) as new_date, co.item, co.quantity, co.cost
from 
    cust_items co
    join (select customer, max(item_date) max_date
          from cust_items ci
          group by customer) m_date
     on (co.customer, co.item_date) 
      = (m_date.customer, m_date.max_date)
);

/* execute 3 times

Statement 'insert into cust_items (select co.customer, add_days(co.item_date, 1) as new_date, co.item, ...' 
successfully executed in 25 ms 530 µs  (server processing time: 14 ms 94 µs) - Rows Affected: 6 

Statement 'insert into cust_items (select co.customer, add_days(co.item_date, 1) as new_date, co.item, ...' 
successfully executed in 9 ms 288 µs  (server processing time: 3 ms 900 µs) - Rows Affected: 6 

Statement 'insert into cust_items (select co.customer, add_days(co.item_date, 1) as new_date, co.item, ...' 
successfully executed in 11 ms 311 µs  (server processing time: 4 ms 586 µs) - Rows Affected: 6 

--> number of new records always the same as only the most recent values are copied
*/
```

The table content now looks like this:

```
/*
CUSTOMER        ITEM_DATE   ITEM            QUANTITY    COST 
Aardvark Inc.   6 Apr 2022  Bird Food       4.5         47.11
Aardvark Inc.   6 Apr 2022  Carrot Cake     3           8.15 
Aardvark Inc.   6 Apr 2022  Yellow Balls    10          23.23
Wolf Ltd.       6 Apr 2022  Black Bile      2           23.23
Wolf Ltd.       6 Apr 2022  Carrot Cake     3           8.15 
Wolf Ltd.       6 Apr 2022  Red Ballon      1           47.11

Aardvark Inc.   7 Apr 2022  Bird Food       4.5         47.11
Aardvark Inc.   7 Apr 2022  Carrot Cake     3           8.15 
Aardvark Inc.   7 Apr 2022  Yellow Balls    10          23.23
Wolf Ltd.       7 Apr 2022  Black Bile      2           23.23
Wolf Ltd.       7 Apr 2022  Carrot Cake     3           8.15 
Wolf Ltd.       7 Apr 2022  Red Ballon      1           47.11

Aardvark Inc.   8 Apr 2022  Bird Food       4.5         47.11
Aardvark Inc.   8 Apr 2022  Carrot Cake     3           8.15 
Aardvark Inc.   8 Apr 2022  Yellow Balls    10          23.23
Wolf Ltd.       8 Apr 2022  Black Bile      2           23.23
Wolf Ltd.       8 Apr 2022  Carrot Cake     3           8.15 
Wolf Ltd.       8 Apr 2022  Red Ballon      1           47.11

Aardvark Inc.   9 Apr 2022  Bird Food       4.5         47.11
Aardvark Inc.   9 Apr 2022  Carrot Cake     3           8.15 
Aardvark Inc.   9 Apr 2022  Yellow Balls    10          23.23
Wolf Ltd.       9 Apr 2022  Black Bile      2           23.23
Wolf Ltd.       9 Apr 2022  Carrot Cake     3           8.15 
Wolf Ltd.       9 Apr 2022  Red Ballon      1           47.11

Wolf Ltd.       10 Apr 2022 Black Bile      2           23.23
Wolf Ltd.       10 Apr 2022 Carrot Cake     3           8.15 
Wolf Ltd.       10 Apr 2022 Red Ballon      1           47.11

--> only Wolf Ltd. has entries on 10/4 as it was the only one starting off with 
    values on 7/4.
*/
```